# Giving user chance to select new option in same program instance

Tags: python-3.x

For my program, I want to give the person using my program the chance to select a different option without having to restart the program itself. I've tried a few different things and I've had no luck successfully doing it. Below is the main part of my code where I attempted to implement a "redo" option.

```
restart = input("Would you like to look at other car insurance companies? y/n: ").lower()
while restart == "y":
    def ins_option():

        while True:
            try:
                ins_num = int(input('Please select the car insurance you want information on:\n1 for {}\n2 for {}\n3 for {}\n4 for {}\n5 for {}\nChoice:'.format(astate, pro, sfarm, lmut, gei)))
            except ValueError:
                print("Your input is not a number, please try again.\n")
            else:
                if 0 >= ins_num or ins_num > len(ins):
                    print("Invalid value, please try again.\n")
                else:
                    return ins_num
    if restart == "n":
        break

option = ins_option()
ins_name = insurance[option - 1]

print("\n Ok, here is information about {}:\n\n {}".format(ins_name,ins[ins_name][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not define a function inside a loop as you are doing. 
A way to do it could be the follow. First define the function:

```
def ins_option():
    while True:
        try:
            ins_num = int(input('Please select the car insurance you want information on:\n1 for {}\n2 for {}\n3 for {}\n4 for {}\n5 for {}\nChoice:'.format(astate, pro, sfarm, lmut, gei)))
        except ValueError:
            print("Your input is not a number, please try again.\n")
        else:
            if 0 >= ins_num or ins_num > len(ins):
                print("Invalid value, please try again.\n")
            else:
                return ins_num
```

Then you call the function until the input is `"n"`:

```
restart="y"
while restart == "y":
    option = ins_option()
    print("\n Ok, here is information about option:", option)
    restart = input("Do you want information about a different car insurance company? y/n: ").lower()
```

Comment: Ok, I got it working to where it asked me if i wanted to look at other options, but when I type 'y', it just asks again. I know I have nothing in it, but I'm not sure how to place my code to go back to the top

Comment: I thought that it is what you wanted. The program asks again the same thing:`Would you like to look at other car insurance companies?` until you digit `"n"`. Which part of the code do you want to repeat from the top?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. Basically I wanted the user to be able to input a number for a certain car insurance. After what they picked was displayed, I wanted a pormpt to ask them if they wanted to select a different car insurance to look at. So, in short, I want to keep running the ins_option() part of the code until the user is satisfied with what they looked at

Comment: No problem! I think the program is already doing that. After the user picks an insurance to look at the program asks if he wants to look at another insurance again until he digits "n". However, I updated the answer, now the program asks again to the user if he wants to select another another car insurance. Let me know whether this is answering your question or I am missing something.

Comment: So I got it working. I had to replace 'restart="y"' with restart = input("Do you want information about a different car insurance company? y/n: ").lower(),  had to delete the restart = n and break line underneath it, and had to place the 'ins_name = insurance[option - 1]' line underneath the 'option = ins_option() line

Comment: Ok good! Yes indeed the break isn't really necessary, since when restart is not "y"  the while stops.